# Domain .com and .ca (SEO point of view)

Tags: dns

I can and will buy 2 domain for a great website (as all the site is)

mydomain.ca and mydomain.com

q1 : What is the best thing to do after it have been buy...
.htaccess redirect the .ca to the .com
make the .ca a exact duplicate of the .com
put some content on the .ca and some on the .com
if i have a forum, but the .net too...

WHAT would you do, what i am missing ?

q2 : If i am using subdomain like forum.mydomain.com it's it good or bad for ranking ?

- The content will be EXACTLY the same... i just like to be able to rank higher on google.ca and be there on google.com... for people lookin for me in .ca i hope to be on the first page, for people looking for me from the world, hope to be in the first 25 hit

Comment: If you're going to do a full redirect, why not do it at the DNS level and make both domains point to the same IP?

Comment: I am looking for the best "result" to get high ranking to google and on other search engine

Comment: "best result" *in which country?*

Comment: Do you have canadian-specific content to offer to your visitors that land on the .ca (such as a CAD currency product catalog) or both domains will contain the same exact data?

Comment: canada... the site content and creator is on canada... but even if i live and do thing in canada.. i NEVER EVER used google.ca we live in a global village, i like to have to world to my services ! not just canada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Webmaster Tools site is the best place to go for information. They address duplicate content here: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=66359

If you want multiple domains going to identical content you should use a "301 Moved Permanently" redirect. That will prevent the page rank from incoming links from being split between the domains.

If you have country-specific content, use separate top level domains.